# Biased Switch statement

Tags: java, switch-statement

With this switch statement only 2nd and 4th case work at a time. Example, with this code only case 'u' and case 'l' work. If I switch places of 'd' & 'u' and 'r' & 'l' only cases 'd' and 'r' will work (I am sure 1st and 3rd case are not executing because the value of coords isn't updating but it should). Does anyone know how to fix this? Any help appreciated.

```
switch (dir.get(0))
{
    case 'd': 
    {
        if (coords[1] + size + 4 < H)
            coords[1] = pos.get(0)[1] + size;
        else 
            coords[1] = 0;
    }
    case 'u': 
    {
        if (coords[1] - size - 4 > 0)
            coords[1] = pos.get(0)[1] - size;
        else 
            coords[1] = H - size;
    }
    case 'r': 
    {
        if (coords[0] + size + 4 < W)
            coords[0] = pos.get(0)[0] + size;
        else 
            coords[0] = 0;
    }
    case 'l':
    {
        if (coords[0] - size - 4 > 0)
            coords[0] = pos.get(0)[0] - size;
        else 
            coords[0] = W - size;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add `break` to the end of your switch cases, otherwise every other case after will execute.

Comment: Oh... I thought they don't need break if they have parentheses. Thanks!